# cannot find iTunes Connect Mobile app when searching iTunes store

Tags: itunes

I am searching for "iTunes Connect Mobile" app by Apple from my iPod touch (has OS 4.0) in the Apple Store, without any luck. Also tried "iTC Mobile" (a name used in some articles about it).

Opening iTunes on mac brings "iTunes Connect Mobile", and the description says it's working on iPod touch OS 3.2 and up. Any clues why iPod touch is not finding it?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 4):

Open this on your device:

http://itunes.com/apps/iTunesConnectMobile

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It's weird though that it's not showing in iTunes search.